# How to loop over rows using raw sql queries in EF 6?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

How to get the values and loop over them from the below query? The query is returning a count.

```
var quantities = db.Database.SqlQuery<List<string>>
        (@"SELECT  Quantity
        FROM   Runlist WHERE(UserId = @userid) 
        GROUP BY Quantity", new SqlParameter("@userid", user.Id)).ToList();

foreach (var qty in quantities)
{

}
```

This is the results of the query.

```
Quantity
---------
1250
1750
2500
5000
5250
6250
11500
12250
12500
15500
17000
164250
```

[image]

Comment: You're already looping over the results. That query isn't returning a count though, it only returns distinct `Quantity` values due to that `GROUP BY`

Comment: remove `GROUP BY Quantity`

Comment: How do I get the value of qty?

Comment: You already retrieve it. Perhaps you should try debugging this code and see what it actually does? Run that query directly and see what it returns?

Comment: I already know what it retrieves and I have debugged it. The debug says count=12. I want to loop over the values returned etc etc

Answer (score 1):

Replace your query like this to get a count of Quantity

```cs
List<string> quantities = new List<string>();
quantities = db.Database.SqlQuery<List<string>>
        (@"SELECT Quantity 
        FROM   Runlist WHERE(UserId = @userid) 
        GROUP BY Quantity", new SqlParameter("@userid", user.Id)).ToList();

foreach (var qty in quantities)
{
 // get value here

}
```

Comment: I don't think everyone understands what I need. I don't want the count, I want the values in the example above. I want to loop over each record and use the values.

Comment: if you just need a list of count then change var quantities to  List<string> quantities = db.Database.SqlQuery<List<string>>
It will return only the list of quantities and you can continue your foreach loop on that list.

Comment: Please check my edit code snippets, hope this is what you want. :)

Comment: The issue was the Type (generic paramater) of Database.SqlQuery, needs to be string, not List<string>

Answer (score 1):

The query call looks wrong to me. The method, Database.SqlQuery<T> will return an IEnumerable<T> - so in your case it would receive IEnumerable<List<string>>, your final ToList() would project as List<List<string>>.

When you foreach over List<List<string>> each item would be List<string>, I can only imagine that the value you are getting is some oddity when EF6 manifests your string value as a list (maybe it's a character number).

The answer would probably be to do Database.SqlQuery<string> instead. As somebody else said, remove GROUP BY Quantity from your SQL if you don't want distinct quantities.

```
var quantities = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>
    (@"SELECT  Quantity
    FROM   Runlist WHERE(UserId = @userid) 
    GROUP BY Quantity", new SqlParameter("@userid", user.Id)).ToList();

foreach (var qty in quantities)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Quantity = " + qty);
}
```

Comment: I do want distinct quantities. As you can see in the image above when I use "qty."  I have no option to use qty.Quantity. I don't know why or how to get the values.

Comment: I can see your code fragment - and you're nearly there, however if you use "string" as the type in your SqlQuery call, you will find that variable 'qty' is the quantity that you are looking for. If you really want to have it manifest as qty.Quantity, then you will need to specify a class with a Quantity property and SqlQuery that e.g. SqlQuery<QuantityWrapperClass>

Comment: I just added a quick edit of your original program.

Comment: Thank you Mark I now understand what I was missing, however I am now getting an error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid.'

Comment: I changed <string> to <int> and that fixed it.